# Import a module with __init__.py withot use file name

Tags: python, package

My python library have this structure:

```
sisipp
├── __init__.py       #1
├── analysis
│   ├── __init__.py   #2
│   └── fil.py
└── core
    ├── __init__.py   #3
    ├── method.py
    └── utils.py
```

This is the first **init**.py:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import
__all__ = ['analysis', 'core']

from . import core
from . import analysis
```

And this is the **init**.py in `core`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
__all__ = ['ob', 'method', 'utils']

from .method import sate
from .utils import load4tar
```

When I load the module `sate` (this in sisipp/core/method.py):

```
from sisipp.method import sate
```

work. My question is, if I like make the import without `.method`

```
from sisipp import sate
```

How I make this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import it in `sisipp/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import
__all__ = ['analysis', 'core', 'sate']

from . import core
from . import analysis
from .core.method import sate
```

Comment: I think you mean `from .core.method import sate` or at least `from .core import sate` (which relies on `core` importing `sate` to its own namespace).

Comment: @Blckknght: I do indeed, thanks. (I don't actually like relative imports much, so I rarely use them and discourage them, but I wanted to keep the same style as the OP.)